# How do I "finish" a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing my first Firebase Cloud Function in TypeScript.  The function queries Firestore looking for a document that matches a parameter.  The documentation says that when using a promise I need to "finish" the promise so that the function knows when it can complete.  How do I do that?  Here is my function.

BTW my function only returns the "not found" result right now.  And it does work.  It does send the response to my client app, but only after the function times out.

```
export const validateMemberPin = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log('pin: ' + request.query.pin);

  const query =  admin.firestore().collection('access').where('memberPin', '==', request.query.pin);

  return query.get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.empty)
      response.json({'result': 'false'});

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud functions have a NodeJS environment, so to end a function, you just need to add a return statement, in your case just add a return before `response.json` like so:

```
return query.get().then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.empty)
    return response.json({'result': 'false'});
 });
```

However, it would be better if you handle both cases:

```
return query.get().then((snapshot) => response.json({'result': !snapshot.empty});
```